# Replacing Array element with same index in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an Array like

```
var myArray = new Array;
```

I have to push some elements to array in such a way that the elements will be replaced with same `index`.

```
Example :

myArray.push(1);
myArray.push(2);
myArray.push(3);
```

so now

```
myArray[0] = 1
myArray[1] = 2
```

now when i will push element `3` then 
`myArray[0]` will be replaced with `3` and `myArray[1]` will be replaced with `1` and the element `2` will be removed.

It will continue according to the number of elements pushed...

Can any body help me with this requirement...

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: possible answer: similar stack http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236515/can-i-limit-the-length-of-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: So i assume 2 is the max legth of the array , am i wrong ?

Comment: I made a little JSfiddle to you : 
http://jsfiddle.net/10woyacm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`push` adds to the end of an array. If you want to add a value to the beginning of an array you can use [`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift).

```
myArray.unshift(3);
```

You can then use `pop` to remove the last element:

```
arr.pop();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/x1zo3e30/1/)

However, what you might need, given that you need to remove the same number of elements from an array that you add is a function that uses `concat` and `slice` instead:

```
function pusher(arr, add) {
  return add.concat(arr).slice(0, arr.length);
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var arr = pusher(arr, [5, 6]); // [5, 6, 1, 2]
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/x1zo3e30/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something in the lines of:

```
myArray.unshift(element);
myArray.pop();
```

Explanation:

- unshift: inserts the element on position 0 and moves all other elements one position to the right
- pop: removes last element from array